# How to get 'http://jabber.org/protocol/nick' extension value in (a)Smack?

Tags: java, xmpp, smack, asmack

I have the following message being received on my client from a PSI client:

```
<message from="testing@example.com/PAT" type="chat" xmlns="jabber:client" id="ab1ca" to="testing2@example.com/Smack">
<active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
<nick xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/nick">testing</nick>
```

How is it that I can parse the nick extension to get the "testing" value?

```
DefaultPacketExtension ext2 = (DefaultPacketExtension) msg.getExtension("nick");
```

Only provides me with the option to get a value using getValue(String) if it's the following [format](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.4.0/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/DefaultPacketExtension.html):

```
<foo xmlns="http://bar.com">
   <color>blue</color>
   <food>pizza</food>
</foo>
```

The embedded packet extension doesn't allow me either, allowing me to only retrieve further packet extensions.

So how is it that I can get the "testing" value if it is not in an XML format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smack has support for XEP-172: Simply use

```
Nick nick = (nick) msg.getExtension("nick");
```

and then

```
nick.getName();
```

to retrieve the nickname. <sup>[javadoc](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/dailybuilds/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/nick/packet/Nick.html#getName%28%29)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I wasn't looking just for the Nick extension per say, but I managed to track it down in aSmack and see how it's done and do the same for other extensions. :)